# How to keep a large value in excel cell?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, export-to-excel

I am preparing a table with values coming from a database.  In the database the columns values have lengthy numbers, but in Excel large numbers are not displaying properly.

For Example: **container id** has value- **201234578000007838920986**

I get this value from the database but Excel displays it **2.01235E+23**

If I widen the cell, it expands to only some extent: **2.01234578000007E+23**

Is there any possible way to fit the value in the Excel cell?  I am using Microsoft Excel 2007.

Comment: You could import the value as text when you import it from the database. Text doesn't get rounded.

Comment: re "the tables data are coming from the database" ... are you using an SQL kind of query? Format the receiving cells and/or use a toChar function if SQL.

Comment: @MikeD I tried the method which you mentioned. converting the columns into TO_CHAR in sql query. But still i am facing same problem.

Comment: additionally formating the output cells as text doesn't help either?

Comment: @MikeD yes, both methods i tried. one is converting into TO_CHAR and another one, externally formatting the cell type as 'Text'. But still i am getting the same answer **'2.01201E+14'**

Comment: @pnuts yes, I tried that method also, but still the output is coming as  **2.01201E+14**.

Answer (score 0):

**Format** the cell before copying as **text**, when copying, paste as then select **keep formatting of cell** (**match destination formatting**) this will allow you to view 201234578000007838920986 in the cell.

Also, the TEXT function converts a numeric value to text and lets you specify the display formatting by using special format strings. so you could use something like =TEXT(A1,"$0.00") which will give you for example $23.00 Search online for all the different options that come with the TEXT function.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is late for the topic, but may helps for the upcoming users. Formatting the cell as number works only for 15 digit numbers, but if the digit range goes beyond 15, instead of numbers 0s are displayed. So for the numbers to be visible irrespective of its length append the digits with no-break space (\u00a0). If you include (') with the number it may look odd. Try it and let me know.